# Laravel - Manipulate data from model

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I may be over complicating this or missing something very simple so forgive me if I am.

I am trying to manipulate/map some data in my model.

A very simple example of what I am trying to do:

I have `$model->attr`, this will return whatever is in my database for that column.

I know that the return will be `1`, `2` or `3`.

When displaying on a view I would like this value to show something different, for the sake of this example lets say `1=>'red'`, `2=>'blue'`, `3=>'green'`.

How would I go about doing this in the model? I have had a look at Accessors & Mutators but not sure if they are the right thing to use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators may be helpful

Comment: I think the mutators are the correct answer you should elaborate this response and post it as answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would need an [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) indeed:

```
public function getNewValueAttribute($value){
    switch($value) {
        case '1':
            return 'red';
        case '2':
            return 'blue';
        case '3':
            return 'green';
    }
}
```

Put that inside your model and it should work perfectly!

Laravel converts the attribute to CamelCase, so `$user->full_name` has an accessor `getFullNameAttribute`, `$user->all_your_base_are_belong_to_us` becomes `getAllYourBaseAreBelongToUsAttribute`.

Comment: I think this is a good answer, however you should leave the breaks after returns.

Comment: Ah thanks! The breaks are a habit. I'll update my answer and remove them!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to output text based on conditions. If it is you can try

```
@if($model->attr==1)
  red
@elseif($model->attr==2)
  blue
@else
  green
@endif
```

Comment: I actually think this isn't what the author looked for. This requires you to put the 3 clauses everywhere you want to output the data

Comment: @ Frank Provost: Yes you are right..I agree with you.

Comment: @MuhammadRizwan  your suggestion would have been okay for a one of case however accepted answer makes this reusable throughout my application, thank you anyway

Comment: You Welcome, Pls click on upward arrow for giving at least point